# Qt: data conversion on the model/view framework

Tags: c++, qt, model, delegates, type-conversion

Where do I have to put data adaption logic, at a delegate level, or at a model level?

With *data adaption logic* I mean when the data must be transformed at retrieval and recording. For example, in *sqlite*, the `date` type doesn't exists and the `QSqlTableModel` retrieves dates as strings (but they are dates, it's just that this is not reflected in the column type), thus making the `QStyledItemDelegate` shows a `QLineEdit` when editing.

To edit it as a date, you can do two things:

- installing a custom delegate which transforms the `QVariant` string to a `QVariant` date and also creates a `QDateEdit` (and the reverse transformation when saving editions).
- deriving a `QSqlTableModel` to do the same transformation for the corresponding columns, without having to install any custom delegate (the `QStyledItemDelegate` will recognize the `QVariant` date type and show a `QDateEdit` automatically).

What must I do, or what is the "standard" or usual way of doing it in Qt?

Pros and cons:

- In the delegate approach, the model is untouched.
- In the model approach, the view is untouched (it doesn't require deriving the view).
- Any view using the model must install the same custom delegate for the corresponding columns. On the model approach, every view sees the changes without installing any delegate, which is, I think, its **best point** in my opinion, since models are thought to be shared, but views aren't.
- A same delegate class can be used for headers too. In the model approach, you have to derive the `headerData`s and `data`s methods if you want to do any conversion over them too.
- On the delegate approach, if you want to change the model of a view, you have to uninstall the previously installed delegates, which forces you to synchronized delegates with models (the delegate is tied to an specific column of an specific table model).

Comment: I would do this at the model level. If you don't want to touch the model you could use a `QIdentityProxyModel` for the data transformation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a viewmodel: an adapter that feeds your view with data formatted correctly for viewing/editing.

Such a viewmodel is implemented as a proxy model. In this specific case, it could be a very simple `QIdentityProxyModel` that converts the string to a date and vice-versa.

Of course the view needs an editor delegate that knows how to handle a `QVariant` that carries a date, I don't recall offhand if Qt provides one by default. If it doesn't, you have to add one. But the concerns are separate: you're imbuing a generic view with the ability to edit dates, and you're imbuing your model with the correct representation of a date. The coupling between the two is minimal: the view needn't be aware of your specific model's peculiarities, and neither is your model aware of anything special in the view itself.